# Using characters as a delimiter for StringTokenizer in Java

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter, stringtokenizer

I am writing a program that takes an input of a list of numbers separated by commas and summing the total of the numbers. For example, I have the string "10, 20, 30, 40, 50"

I want to extract each number, "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" separately from the string and finding the sum of the list of numbers.

I found a solution, however, I find my code a bit messy and when I go back and look at it, I'll have quite a few "WTF"'s in a minute.

So,

I was wondering if there was a better way to write the following line:

```
StringTokenizer inputTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, "- ,\\n\\r\\t\\b\\fabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

**My goal is that I want the program to use every character that is a non number as a delimiter for StringTokenizer.**
So for instance the string `"11abc33"` should split into `"11"` and `"33"`.

Here is my source code of what I came up with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        //Prompts user to enter a series of numbers and stores it in the String "input"
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a series of numbers separated by commas.");

        //total stores the sum of each number entered
        int total = 0;

        if ((input != null)) //checks if the user didn't cancel or quit the program
        {

            //sets every alphabetical character in the input String to lowercase
            input = input.toLowerCase();

            //creates a StringTokenizer that uses commas and white spaces as delimiters
            StringTokenizer inputTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, "- ,\\n\\r\\t\\b\\fabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

            //sums the total of each number entry
            while (inputTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                total = total + Integer.parseInt(inputTokenizer.nextToken());
            }
        } else {
            //exit the program because the user hit cancel or exit
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //display the sum of the total number entries
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total: " + total);

    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: so you want to split an input string using a space or a comma between digits?

Comment: yes, or any non-numerical character

Comment: Your delimiters seem crazy complicated if you only want to split on commas. And if you do want to use all those delimiters, you might want to check out the String.split() method, and use regex which can express all that in a much cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `StringTokenizer` constructor or factory method that does what you want any more simply.  If you must have a `StringTokenizer` then I don't think there's a better way to get one, except inasmuch as you can tweak the characters in the delimiter string.

You wrote

> My goal is that I want the program to use every character that is a non number as a delimiter for StringTokenizer.

but that seems a bit narrow-minded.  It seems the most important thing would be the *tokens*, not the tokenizer, and if that's indeed the case for you then the regex-based `String.split()` might offer a satisfactory alternative:

```
for (String token : input.split("[^0-9]+")) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(token);

    // ...
}
```

That takes you literally at your word, that you want to consider *everything* that is non-number as delimiter.

There are other regex-based solutions as well, such as using a pattern that matches one number to iterate through the string via `Matcher.find()`.

Comment: Wouldnt this just split numbers 0-9? What if I wanted to split numbers 0 to infinity?

Comment: @TommySaechao, no, it will split numbers of any length. 0-9 just means, that your numbers have contain only chars from 0 to 9. And + after means length from one char to infinite. This answer is best one.

Comment: @TommySaechao, the regex string on which I suggest splitting matches any sequence of one or more characters (the `+`) that are not (`[^]`) decimal digits (`0-9`).  Each maximal run matching that regex will be taken as a delimiter, so the resulting split strings will be what's left between: the digit runs you want.

Answer (score 4):

note that stringtokenizer separates numbers and substrings using spaces in normal mode. i mean using this constructor `StringTokenizer(string)`

but you can use another constructor to separate numbers using strTokenizer

```
StringTokenizer(String str, String delim)
```

which you can use `","` as delim parameter and all substrings will be separated according to `","` ,lock at this example:

```
    String numbers = "10,20,30,40,50,60,70";
    StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(numbers, ",");
    int sum=0;
    while (t.hasMoreTokens()) {
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(t.nextToken());
    }
    System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
```

you can also do it simply using `split(String regex)` method in `String` class
here is an example and solution for you.

```
    String numbers = "10,20,30,40,50,60,70";// all numbers

    String[] separated_numbers = numbers.split(",");// separate them by comma

    // calculating sum
    int sum = 0;
    for (String number : separated_numbers) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(number);
    }
    // print sum
    System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer got down voted. It's exactly how I would solve this problem.

Comment: I downvoted because if you take a deep look at the OP question, there is a contradiction, he want to get the sum of all digits, what ever is between degits, the input can be `qsdqskdqskdqsd254131qdsdgkljf`

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond lock at the question, he does not want to calculate sum of all digits see :"I want to extract each number, "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" separately from the string and finding the sum of the list of numbers."

Comment: Yes, i know it, it's what i saied just before, but looking at the string tokenizer, the input can contains eveiry character.

Comment: lock at this `StringTokenizer(String str, String delim)` first argument is input ,other one is delim and delim argument are the delimiters for separating tokens. Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens, input is just some integers separated by comma,it contains only `0-9` and `,`

Comment: According to task description, delimiter can contain any character, not only `,`.

Comment: @KenBekov understood what i meant, he want to splited by ANY characted, OP is not sure at all to get an input separated by comma. Take a closer look at the wuestion (particulary the EDIT part at the end)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using regex

```
do {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a series of numbers separated by commas.");

    int total = 0;

    if ((input != null))
    {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(-?[0-9]+.[0-9]*)+").matcher(input);
        // when using regex, the first group is always the full text, so we skip it.
        for (int i = 1; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            total = total + Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(i));
        }
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total: " + total);

} while (true);
```

Comment: This solution should handle properly all numbers `-12`, `12`, `12.34` both works

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all non number characters into one single character, then using `split` method to get a all numbers array.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        //Prompts user to enter a series of numbers and stores it in the String "input"
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a series of numbers separated by commas.");

        //total stores the sum of each number entered
        int total = 0;

        if ((input != null)) //checks if the user didn't cancel or quit the program
        {
            String[] characterTokens = input.split("[^0-9]+");
            for (String characterToken : characterTokens) {
                input.replace(characterToken, ",");
            }
            String[] numberTokens = input.split(",");
            for (String numberToken: numberTokens) {
                total += Integer.parseInt(numberToken);
            }
        } else {
            //exit the program because the user hit cancel or exit
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //display the sum of the total number entries
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total: " + total);

    } while (true);
}
```